# Is it better to toggle display: none; on several related items individually, or wrap them in another div and toggle it?

Tags: css, wrapper

Let's say I have three div elements with classes `a`, `b`, and `c`, respectively. I want to use css to toggle the display of these elements between `none` and `block`, depending on whether or not a parent element has a class of `current` or is `hovered`. The elements always toggle together, never individually.

I can `a)` toggle the display on the elements individually, or I can `b)` wrap them in a fourth div that is otherwise non-functional and toggle display on that element instead.

So, for instance, it's this:

```
<li>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
</li>

li > .a,
li > .b,
li > .c {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .a,
li.current > .a,
li:hover > .b,
li.current > .b,
li:hover > .c,
li.current > .c {
  display: block;
}
```

versus this:

```
<li>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</li>

li > .wrap {
  display: none;
}

li:hover > .wrap,
li.current > .wrap {
  display: block;
}
```

There's an obvious `code-cleanliness` difference in the css, at the expense of some additional html structure, but I think the net is in favor of using the wrapper.

I'm wondering if there are any other benefits or costs, such as browser performance, one way or the other between the two options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to do either :). You're using CSS!! Consider the following:

```
<!-- Notice the space between the class names -->
<li class="switch">
    <div class="a toggle"> ... </div>
    <div class="b toggle"> ... </div>
    <div class="c toggle"> ... </div>
</li>
```

Now, you can keep your styling elements for `a`, `b`, `c`. By adding a simple CSS style, you can cover both of your sets of needs quickly and easily. Additionally, its abstracted, so you could use it in more places, when needed. No addition of DOM elements necessary and no real changes to your current styling code for `a`, `b`, and `c`. Furthermore, your switch doesn't even have to be an `li`.

```
.switch:hover > .toggle,
.switch.current > .toggle { display:block;
}
```

**Additional Information on CSS classes**

Elements may be of more than one class. By utilizing this, you can separate pseudo-functionality from look inside your CSS. When utilizing multiple classes, the browser will combine the rules of both to complete its style.

Consider the following:

```
<body class="article twocolumns">
```

- The `body` element will have whatever html positioning, and overall document overrides.
- The `article` class would have whatever presentation styles you might need.
- The `twocolumns` would have whatever layout parameters your require.

You may provide individual or combination styles, like so:

```
body { 
    margin:0 auto; 
}
.article { 
    background-color:white;
}
.twocolumns {
    background-image: url("divider.png");
}

/* This is a combination style. Notice no space between the two classes. */
.article.twocolumns > div { 
    padding:15px; 
    float:left; 
    width:50%; 
}
/* A possible further extension. */
.article.onecolumn > div {
    padding:20px; 
    float:none; 
    width:100%; 
}
.article.threecolumn > div { 
    padding:10px; 
    float:left; 
    width:33%; 
}
```

Learning to do things in this way has a number of benefits. It allows you to abstract functionality, layout and presentation elements easier allowing you to "port" either to other web projects you might have. It allows you to find what works cross-browser more effectively for more unified look and feel. It also reduces the tendency to accidentally tweak rules that might not be related to your issue. Finally, it reduces your dependency on extraneous DOM elements allowing you to keep your performance.

Hope this helps.
FuzzicalLogic

Answer (score 1):

I would favour the cleaner HTML, messier CSS option, because:

- The HTML can then describe the actual data to be displayed more closely.
- The CSS is the more likely to change, for example you might want class 'c' to remain visible throughout, and having independant control over this from the outset will make updating easier.

As for browser performance, I would say having to parse a few more lines of CSS will be far quicker than creating a new DOM object for the extra div element, with all the hooks into javascript events that this entails.

Comment: +1 on all three points. I hadn't thought about the issue of matching the HTML structure to "reality" of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you make changes to the DOM, you always need to keep the number of changes to a minimum.  Changes to the DOM initiates the browser to reflow - to run through all the elements on the page and "redraw" them.  This happens pretty fast, but it doesn't take much before you see jitters (most notable with animations).

If you have the option to incur only 1 reflow instead 3, as a rule you should take that option. When you are talking about only a few dozen reflows that only happen once (a click, for example), you don't see much savings.  But when you start getting into animations, or animating something while hiding others the savings become much more noticable.

Update:

This answer is assuming you are using javascript, because the question states "wrap them in another div and toggle it".  If you are not using javascript to dynamically add or remove css classes, then you are not toggling anything (but rather simply setting them), and also this answer doesn't apply.

Comment: Just using css here, no javascript. However, great point you've made here.